# What cases does react portal have when there we have html dialog element?

Tags: html, reactjs, dialog, react-portal

After learning lit element (after react) for a bit, I’ve got a question: what use cases does react portal have when we have an html dialog element?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a React developer, but portals in web frameworks as a concept are for elements that need to be in a place under DOM tree other than the component they are defined in.

In that sense `<dialog>` elements are handling several use cases natively. So yes, if you need a dialog nowadays I'd go with `<dialog>` rather than using a portal.